# Targeting layout outside layout folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

TL;DR version: is there any way to target layout nested in `views/spree/layout` with `layout` method ?

Hello. I'm using mercury editor and the problem is with targeting layout outside views/layout folder.
my controller is like that now:

```
class HomepagesController < Spree::BaseController

  layout :layout_with_mercury

  def show
     @page = Spree::Homepage.first
  end

  private

  def layout_with_mercury
    # this should be pointed to spree/layout/spree_application but ...nope
    !params[:mercury_frame] && is_editing? ? 'mercury' : 'application'
  end

  def is_editing?
    flash[:editing] == 'true'
  end

end
```

I'm using spree so that means layout sits in `views/spree/layout/layout.html.erb`. layout_with_mercury returns `mercury` or `application` and then look for layout with returned string in name in layout folder. My question is: is there any way to target layout nested in `views/spree/layout`?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can try this

```
layout '../spree/layout/layout_name.html.erb'
```

it actually take relative path so

Comment: You dont want to use a relative path here, and the extension, or format of the request shouldnt be included in the filename.

Answer (score -1):

layout "spree/layout/layout" problem solved. You want to use absolute paths relative to the views directory, not relative paths.